# rails rendering partial with collection / other class is in charge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, render, partial

Somewhat new to rails, longtime programmer.  I've got a question about views, controllers and partials really - wondering if I have this setup well.

I've got a pages controller, and on the index page (really the pages index method) I've got a partial in layouts called featured (ie app/views/layouts/_featured.html.erb) -- I've also got a Featured class.  I would like basically the index of the featured class to be drawn here. But of course it's not working. SO the question is:

In the page itself I've got the <%= render 'features/index' %> which I'm beginning to think is the wrong way to go..

Do I axe this partial method and just call <%= render 'features/index' %> and let everything progress natively or

What would be the proper way of routing the featured collection to the partial?  Since the controller is actually Pages it seems like I'm fighting against the tide.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render 'features/index' %>
```

Doing this is wrong given your description. This will try to render a partial from `app/views/features/_index.html.erb` which you haven't mentioned.

To render the partial at `app/views/layouts/_featured.html.erb` you would do *(perhaps a bit more verbose that is necessary)*

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/featured" %>
```

The best suggestion I can offer is to pass a collection to this partial

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/featured", locals: { features: @features } %>
```

Since it seems your intention is for this partial to appear as a piece of a **layout** I will assume you wish for this partial to appear on multiple pages. This means on multiple actions you will need to have assigned the set of `Feature` instances this `@features` instance variable. One way to do this is a `before_action`.

```
before_action :setup_features

# ...

private

  def setup_features
    @features = Feature.all
  end
```

A good place to start learning more about filters is in the **[Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)**

Answer (score 0):

The partial at "app/view/layouts/_featured.html.erb" can only be rendered with

```
render 'featured'
```

and not `'featured/index'`

`render 'featured/index'` will render "app/views/layouts/featured/_index.html.erb

Comment: render '/featured/index' will render "app/views/featured/_index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Since the pages controller is really rendering the main index page in it's def index, all I had to do was @features = Feature.all and the variable is available for the partial pulled into the index page.

I need to get used to how simple rails is coming from other languages / frameworks.